# Save print settings from windows print settings dialog

Tags: c#, windows, printing

I call printer settings dialog via windows API

```
 private void OpenPrinterPropertiesDialog(PrinterSettings printerSettings)
        {
            IntPtr hDevMode = printerSettings.GetHdevmode(printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings);
            IntPtr pDevMode = GlobalLock(hDevMode);
            //int sizeNeeded = DocumentProperties(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, IntPtr.Zero, printerSettings.PrinterName, pDevMode, ref pDevMode, 0);
            int sizeNeeded = DocumentProperties(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, IntPtr.Zero, printerSettings.PrinterName, IntPtr.Zero, pDevMode, 0);
            IntPtr devModeData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeNeeded);
            DocumentProperties(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle, IntPtr.Zero, printerSettings.PrinterName, devModeData, pDevMode, 14);
            GlobalUnlock(hDevMode);
            printerSettings.SetHdevmode(devModeData);
            printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings.SetHdevmode(devModeData);
            GlobalFree(hDevMode);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(devModeData);
        }
```

My problem is that the settings are not saved. The settings should be saved on operating system level so that these settings stay for every application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this post on msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c65f924-68b9-4e45-a416-2f20e30faa1f/dialog-for-printer-properties?forum=netfxbcl)?

It seems that you should be calling

```
IntPtr hDevMode = printerSettings.GetHdevmode();
```

instead of

```
IntPtr hDevMode = printerSettings.GetHdevmode(printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings);
```

And I'd also be interested where the argument `14` in `DocumentProperties` comes from. Shouldn't that be `DM_OUT_BUFFER`?